# Posting to Facebook from Google+

Tags: twitter, google-plus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send updates from Google Plus to Twitter / Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/send-updates-from-google-plus-to-twitter-facebook)

How do I post something to Facebook from Google+?

I thought there was some type of plugin or Google Chrome extension for this, but I cannot find it at the moment.

Is it possible?

Comment: Isn't Google+ supposed to, you know, *replace* Facebook?

Comment: Perhaps but there are still more people on Facebook and I'd like to just post in Google+ (because of its better targeting with Circles) and cross-post to Facebook.

Comment: @Mark no G+ doesn't aim at _replacing_ but rather _competing_ with FB. There's room for both, just for different uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to https://www.facebook.com/mobile/
2. Get your email address at `Upload via Email`
3. Create a new circle on Google+ (let's call it `Facebook`)
4. Add the email from step 2 to this circle
5. For every post you want to share to Facebook add the `Facebook` circle to your post (remember to check `Notify about this post` for this circle)

This works however only for around 50 characters as Facebook uses the subject line and Google+ truncates it.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how good it is, but [extended share](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oenpjldbckebacipkfbcoppmiflglnib#) for Chrome does what you ask.

Comment: I think this has been shut down as of the 7 of July.

Answer (score 2):

There's an online app that sends google+ updates to twitter and facebook at http://netvaniplus.netvani.com

It uses OAuth2