# Send updates from Google Plus to Twitter / Facebook

Tags: twitter, google-plus

Is there any way to post Google+ status updates to Twitter / Facebook?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16921/posting-to-facebook-from-google addresses this for Facebook. I haven't yet seen any information about doing it for Twitter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have recently started using [ManageFlitter](http://manageflitter.com/plus). Once you sign up and associate your Twitter account and Google+ profile, it Tweets all *Public* posts you make to Google+.

([Review by Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5825365/manageflitter-automatically-sends-public-google%252B-posts-to-twitter))

Answer (score 1):

There's a chrome extension that provides you with a "Share on" link that can post to Facebook, Twitter and LinkedIn.

Article: http://chromestory.com/2011/07/google-plus-extension-for-chrome/

Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oenpjldbckebacipkfbcoppmiflglnib

Answer (score 1):

[This IFTTT recipe](http://ifttt.com/recipes/16827) does it.

I use it to selectively send Google Plus updates into Twitter.

Answer (score 0):

[gplus.sagg.im](http://gplus.sagg.im/) purports to provide a gateway for sending from Google+ to Facebook, Twitter, and Identi.ca.

1. Sign in on the site with Identi.ca, Twitter and/or Facebook
2. Once you have connected, you will be given an authentication string. Create a Google+ post containing your authentication string and share it only with `+Agent G`
3. You can now sync G+ posts to your connected account(s) by simply sharing your post with `+Agent G`

Answer (score 0):

There's an online application that sends Google+ updates to Twitter and Facebook at http://netvaniplus.netvani.com.

It uses [OAuth 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0).

Answer (score 0):

There's an [ifttt](http://ifttt.com/) recipe that should work.

[Currently it doesn't for me](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22987/how-to-use-ifttt-to-post-google-updates-to-facebook), but I hope that will be resolved.