# How to use ifttt to post Google+ updates to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, google-plus, if-this-then-that

I found [this recipe](http://ifttt.com/recipes/1813), but it doesn't work.

I put in either `https://plus.google.com/103156295300828440975` or `http://plu.sr/feed.php?plusr=103156295300828440975`, but I keep getting an error

```
Trigger field Not a valid feed url, missing feed title
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It isn't working because the http://plu.sr site is down.

[image: Service down! Oh noes!]

Try using a different Google+ RSS Feed provider such as http://googleplusrss.nodester.com

You just add you Google+ ID to the end of the URL - like this > http://googleplusrss.nodester.com/103156295300828440975

Comment: Hmm, I saw plu.sr was down, but I assumed for some reason that the original profile URL would work. Thanks.